# How do I increment the rotation property of this box one degree at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've wrote the following code in an attempt to rotate the box identified as "player" by one single degree to the left every time I strike the left arrow key on the key board. I tried setting the initial value of the degree by declaring a variable called "numberD" and setting it to 0. Then I incremented this variable with the numberD++; statement. Then I tried to attach the value from numberD into the statement following it by inserting it into the rotate degrees statement.

Im not getting any syntax errors however the box is not moving, i know the keystroke is working because i attached a console log to fire every time i strike the left key. i think my issue is that when i declare the numberD it doesn't know to connect it the the transform property of the CSS element player. 
Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thx!

Also heres a *[CODEPEN LINK](https://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/WEraVK)* for this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #1f1f2e;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#arena {
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
#player {
    background-color: white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}
</style>
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);

function keyBoardInput() {
    var i = event.keyCode;
    if (i == 37) {
      numberD = 0;
      numberD ++;
      document.getElementById('player').style.transform = "rotate(" + 
      numberD +"deg)";

    console.log('fired');
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="arena">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
</body>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You're resetting the value of `numberD` back to `0` with every call to `keyBoardInput`. You need to initialize the variable outside of that function.

Comment: Good point, just tried it, however box still wont move? https://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/WEraVK?editors=0010

Comment: I meant that you need to remove the `numberD = 0;` statement and move it outside of the function. [Like this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oebQXY?editors=0010)

Comment: ok it works, yes thx for explaining that! i see where i went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the function is called, you reset the value for the rotation: `numberD = 0;`

To fix this you have to declare the variable outside of the function. You could do this by defining it as a document wide variable: `document.numberD = 0;`

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);
document.numberD = 0;

    function keyBoardInput() {
    var i = event.keyCode;

    if (i == 37) {

      document.numberD++;
        document.getElementById('player').style.transform = "rotate(" + document.numberD + "deg)";
        console.log('fired');
      }
    }
```

And here is a [working example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WErYva)